# Ayuda con procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Ayuda, necesito crear un procedimiento almacenado en JAVA EE ( jsf+ejb+jpa) que me permita en la tabla marcacion con los siguiente campos empleado(int), fecha(date), estado(char(20)) hacer los siguiente:

Listar los datos de la tabla pasando como parametros el empleado y la fecha,posteriormente recorrer esos registros y cambiar el estado con el que inicialmente fueron guardados, salvo el primer registro y luego llamarlo desde java EE

Comment: La idea es un ejemplo de como hacerlo no que me lo hagan aclaro

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado? En la documentación de MySQL hay muchos ejemplos de procedimientos almacenados. También hay en línea varios tutoriales, e incluso aquí [hay varias preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+procedimiento+almacenado) que tratan sobre el tema.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias si he visto la documentación de MySQL y trato de guiarme, la verdad no he hecho procedimientos almacenados y como es tan particular lo que requiero, pensaba que ya alguien habia hecho algo parecido, lo que intento decir es que por la premura del proyecto en el que estoy trabajando me queda mas complicado.

Comment: La intención del sitio es ayudar, pero con preguntas como la tuya no se puede ayudar. Se necesita un punto de partida, un fallo sobre el código o algo así. Comprenderás que es difícil que alguien te aporte una respuesta sin saber siquiera qué tablas manejas, en qué contexto está tu programa, etc. Recomendaría que te centres en lo que dice la documentación, que hagas ensayos y entonces plantees la pregunta concreta sobre el fallo. Incluso si tienes 10 fallos puedes plantear 10 preguntas, pero sería sobre algo concreto. El sitio funciona así.

Comment: Creo que puedo ayudarte, pásame unos datos de ejemplo iniciales y los valores a los que querrías cambiarlos. Lo del procedimiento almacenado no acabo de verlo necesario, ¿no te vale con dos consultas que lanzas desde JAVA EE?